# What does `runtime: false` mean in the Mixfile dependencies?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

From the [`mix deps`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html#module-dependency-definition-options) documentation:

> `:runtime` - whether the dependency is part of runtime applications.
>   If the `:applications` key is not provided in `def application` in
>   your mix.exs file, Mix will automatically included all dependencies as
>   a runtime application, except if `runtime: false` is given. Defaults
>   to true.

According to [`mix compile.app`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Compile.App.html) docs:

> `:applications` - all applications your application depends on at
>   runtime. By default, this list is automatically inferred from your
>   dependencies. Mix and other tools use the application list in order to
>   start your dependencies before starting the application itself.

Does this mean that adding `runtime: false` to a dependency would make it **not** started as part of the application's supervision tree, but its functions would be available at compile-time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like you mentioned, that's exactly the case. Marking a dependency `runtime: false` will not start it as part of the application supervision tree when your main application is started.

Before Elixir 1.4 we had to individually specify the applications that needed to be started by putting them in `applications`:

```elixir
def application do
  [applications: [:logger, :bamboo]]
end
```

Now we use `extra_applications` instead and mark the specific dependencies `runtime: false` to remove them from the applications list at runtime.

Comment: The historical side note was especially helpful, thanks!